# FindProfilesByUserName throws duplicate key error

Tags: c#, sitecore, profile, sitecore6

Using Sitecore 6.6.current I'm trying to programmatically access a user's profile.

I'm hoping that I can find any users who have been marked as admins, but no longer have an account, so that I can then remove their admin flag.

As a test I'm running this against my own account, as follows:

```
var profiles = ProfileManager.FindProfilesByUserName(
    ProfileAuthenticationOption.Authenticated,
    @"domain\userName"
);
```

Unfortunately when I do this I get the following error:

**System.ArgumentException : Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'domain\userName' Key being added: 'domain\userName'**

While I understand the error, I'm not sure how I can resolve the issue, since it's using the standard  `System.Web.Profile` call.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This didn't resolve my issue, but it does appear that Sitecore was saving these active directory accounts without the domain.

Discovered by looping through the users and dumping user names:

```
var allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
if (allUsers.Count > 0)
{
    actionResults.InnerHtml += allUsers.Count + "<br />";

    try
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var user in allUsers)
        {
            actionResults.InnerHtml += user.ToString() + "<br />";
            count++;
            if (count > 50)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }
}
```